# Extract Historical Status for list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

TableA has a list of historical statuses for an entity. These can also be reversed, if reversed the row needs to be ignored.

```
EntityID  |  StatusDate  |  Status  |  IsReversed
-------------------------------------------------
1         |  2014-01-15  |  A       |  NULL
1         |  2014-06-17  |  B       |  Y
1         |  2015-01-19  |  C       |  NULL
```

TableB has a list of maintenance dates for the entity

```
EntityID  |  MaintDate
-----------------------
1         |  2014-02-20
1         |  2014-03-30
1         |  2015-11-22
```

I would like to produce a list of the maintenance dates which also lists the status of the entity as at the maintenance date.

I've been shown how to retrieve an individual status for one individual date

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  Status
FROM
  TableA
WHERE
  StatusDate < '2014-03-30' AND IsReversed != 'Y'
ORDER BY 
  StatusDate DESC
```

But I can't work out how to integrate this into a query to retrieve the status for every date.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the actual query #SITELIST is TableB and "LNSP_UAT.dbo.INSTALLSTATUS" is TableA:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    I.INSTALL [INSTALL]
    ,RD.GBR$CDATE [ENDDATE]
    ,RD.GBR$PDATE [STARTDATE]

INTO #SITELIST

FROM
    LNSP_UAT.dbo.INSTALL I
    LEFT JOIN LNSP_UAT.dbo.GBBILLREG RG ON RG.GBB$INSTALL = I.INSTALL
    LEFT JOIN LNSP_UAT.dbo.GBREGISTER RD ON RD.GBR$BREGKEY = RG.GBB$REGKEY AND RD.GBR$STATUS = 25 AND RD.GBR$CTYPE IN ('N','D','A','G','S')


SELECT
    SL.INSTALL
    ,SL.STARTDATE
    ,SL.ENDDATE
    ,ST.ISSTATUS

FROM
    #SITELIST SL
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            ST.ISSTATUS
        FROM
            LNSP_UAT.dbo.INSTALLSTATUS ST
        WHERE
            ST.ISINSTALL = SL.INSTALL
            AND ST.ISREVERSE != 'Y'
            AND ST.ISEFFDATE <= SL.STARTDATE
        ORDER BY
            ISEFFDATE DESC
    ) A
    ORDER BY ENDDATE DESC


DROP TABLE #SITELIST
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT
    b.*, a.Status
FROM TableB b
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Status
    FROM TableA
    WHERE
        EntityID = b.EntityID
        AND IsReversed != 'Y'
        AND StatusDate <= b.MaintDate
   ORDER BY StatusDate DESC
) a
```

Comment: This script returned the following error:  "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 The multi-part identifier "a.Status" could not be bound."

Comment: Did you put an alias on the `OUTER APPLY`?

Comment: Yes, had A as the alias.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: @Bric It should be `A.ISSTATUS` instead of `ST.ISSTATUS` in your outer `SELECT`.

Comment: That makes sense, however it now just returns NULL for ISSTATUS in every row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    b.*, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 
        Status
    FROM
      TableA
    WHERE
      EntityID = b.EntityID
      AND IsReversed != 'Y' AND StatusDate < b.MaintDate 
    ORDER BY 
      StatusDate DESC) as status
FROM TableB b
```

Comment: The reference to TableB.MaintDate, in the nested Select statement's Where clause, is not valid.

Comment: sorry i missed the link between the entity ids, try now.